# Trying to center text in a multiline table cell

Tags: tables, center

I want the text in each cell to be centered horizontally.  But it isn't even though the tabular settings are 'c'.  Note I am not trying to use multirow - this is a single row with two lines of text in each cell.  Maybe \parbox is not the right way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
\parbox[c]{1.4cm}{foo\\longer} &
\parbox[c]{1.4cm}{bar\\center} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simplest, in my opinion, would be to load the `makecell` package and use the eponymous command.

Answer (score 2):

two more solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
with \verb+makecell+:

\medskip
    \begin{tabular}{ |wc{14mm}|wc{14mm}| }
\makecell{foo\\ longer} 
    & \makecell{bar\\ center}
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
with \verb+tabularray+:

\medskip
    \begin{tblr}{ |Q[c,14mm]|Q[c,14mm]| }
{foo\\ longer}
    & {bar\\ center}
    \end{tblr}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Using `tabularray` and column specification as are in above example, you not need to manually split text in cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{ |Q[c,14mm]|Q[c,14mm]| }
foo longer
    &  bar center
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

**Addendum:**

In the case, that table cells can have natural width, as suggested @L.J.R. in his comment below (thank you very much), than you can omit their width prescription:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
with \verb+makecell+:

\medskip
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
\makecell{foo\\ longer} 
    & \makecell{bar\\ center}
    \end{tabular}

\bigskip
with \verb+tabularray+:

\medskip
    \begin{tblr}{ |c|c| }
{foo\\ longer}
    & {bar\\ center}
    \end{tblr}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: with `tabularray`, you can even remove the `14mm` to use natural widths.

Comment: @L.J.R., you are right, but I keep this width since OP nested `\parbox`  width such width. I will add to answer addendum with with suggestion ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional packages use a nested `tabular` instead of the `parbox`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ |c|c| }
        \begin{tabular}{c}foo\\ longer\end{tabular} &
        \begin{tabular}{c}bar\\ center\end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```